# Collecting raw GNSS data on various Android devices

Tags: geolocation, location-services

I'm looking at post processing raw GNSS data from various devices to improve the accuracy of the collected points.

We have field staff out collecting points with Zebra TC56 running Android 8.1, Zebra TC57 running Android 10 and a Samsung X Cover Pro running Android 13. Their points have an accuracy of roughly 2-3m which isn't good enough for what we want. So I want to take the raw GNSS data and use RINEX data from the CORSnet to increase the accuracy.

Do these devices capture raw GNSS data and store it whenever you use the in-built GNSS receiver, or do you need to tell it to capture the raw data? Do you need to run a third party app to capture the raw GNSS data?

Google has the GNSSLogger app but I'm not sure if that runs whilst using another app or do you need the app open.

How do I isolate the raw GNSS receiver data to the points in need? It looks like the GNSSLogger app just perpetually runs until you tell it to stop.

I understand this is multiple questions in one but I look at it as sub questions for one big question. I can ask them separately if needed.

Comment: [Raw GNSS Measurements](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/gnss#release) may help

Comment: Related: [Access to raw GPS / GNSS measurements on WearOS 3.0+](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248992/44325) (not answered yet)